Why does only one Hook Modifier work when I have two F-curves manipulating different points on a cloth string in Blender?
I'm attempting to create a loose waveform effect on a piece of string (cloth) in Blender to simulate drum vibrations.
I've applied three Hook Modifiers along the string's length and baked their Z-location using separate F-curves from drum tracks (Bass, Snare, Hi-hat). However, only the bass drum's Hook modifier pulls up the string effectively. The others move but fail to influence the string's shape. Adjusting the Hook modifier strength hasn't resolved the issue.
Interestingly, when the hook modifiers are positioned below the Cloth modifier, it works, but doesn't produce the desired string ripples.
As you can see in the image the far left hook modifier has pulled up the string with it, sending ripples up the string - but the middle hook has moved correctly but not taken the string with it.

Any insights or solutions would be greatly appreciated.


Hello maybe you need to make sure that you have selected the handles and not only the vertex when you have hooked the curve?

pls provide blend file, because we have no idea what your settings are except the little ones you wrote us. thx.

I would suggest testing with manual keys to knock one variable out of the pipeline, and if still failing, share that file on https://blend-exchange.com/

If you're talking about Empty.003, the vertex that it is supposed to move is not assigned to the Pin Group of the Cloth simulation, so it won't be hooked by the empty, assign it to the vertex group:

